# How to start fileserver on aerokube selenoid docker image

Tags: docker, selenoid

I have followed instructions from the post https://medium.com/@aandryashin/selenium-done-in-60-seconds-176796f8bdc7 to get stated with Selenoid.

I was able to get the docker image up and running and connect.

```
2018/05/07 06:24:15 Loading configuration files...
2018/05/07 06:24:15 Loaded configuration from [/etc/selenoid/browsers.json]
2018/05/07 06:24:15 Using default containers log configuration because of: read error: open config/container-logs.json: no such file or directory
2018/05/07 06:24:15 Timezone: Local
2018/05/07 06:24:15 Listening on :4444
2018/05/07 08:45:12 [NEW_REQUEST]
2018/05/07 08:45:12 [NEW_REQUEST_ACCEPTED]
2018/05/07 08:45:12 Locating the service for chrome 
2018/05/07 08:45:12 Using default version: 66.0
2018/05/07 08:45:12 Using docker service for chrome 66.0
2018/05/07 08:45:12 Creating Docker container selenoid/chrome:66.0 ...
2018/05/07 08:45:12 [STARTING_CONTAINER]
2018/05/07 08:45:13 [CONTAINER_STARTED] [a11420c1b6539c0121002b3e8318b726f58f8056aa23e04c011330c476963550] [807.78967ms]
2018/05/07 08:45:14 [SERVICE_STARTED] [a11420c1b6539c0121002b3e8318b726f58f8056aa23e04c011330c476963550] [907.160923ms]
2018/05/07 08:45:14 proxying requests to: http://172.17.0.3:4444/
2018/05/07 08:45:14 [SESSION_ATTEMPTED] [http://172.17.0.3:4444/] [1]
2018/05/07 08:45:18 [SESSION_CREATED] [b71385f73d6cc48febcb357abe3246cf] [http://172.17.0.3:4444/]
2018/05/07 08:45:36 [SESSION_DELETED] [b71385f73d6cc48febcb357abe3246cf]
2018/05/07 08:45:36 [REMOVE_CONTAINER] [a11420c1b6539c0121002b3e8318b726f58f8056aa23e04c011330c476963550]
2018/05/07 08:45:36 [CONTAINER_REMOVED] [a11420c1b6539c0121002b3e8318b726f58f8056aa23e04c011330c476963550]
2018/05/07 08:46:07 [NEW_REQUEST]
2018/05/07 08:46:07 [NEW_REQUEST_ACCEPTED]
2018/05/07 08:46:07 Locating the service for chrome 
2018/05/07 08:46:07 Using default version: 66.0
2018/05/07 08:46:07 Using docker service for chrome 66.0
2018/05/07 08:46:07 Creating Docker container selenoid/chrome:66.0 ...
2018/05/07 08:46:07 [STARTING_CONTAINER]
2018/05/07 08:46:07 [CONTAINER_STARTED] [d6f151bcad639271922fe65182b0e09fd1a4fbfdcc0b8b4374da02f2f5b1d69d] [410.578697ms]
2018/05/07 08:46:08 [SERVICE_STARTED] [d6f151bcad639271922fe65182b0e09fd1a4fbfdcc0b8b4374da02f2f5b1d69d] [142.662491ms]
2018/05/07 08:46:08 proxying requests to: http://172.17.0.3:4444/
2018/05/07 08:46:08 [SESSION_ATTEMPTED] [http://172.17.0.3:4444/] [1]
2018/
```

Now I want to use the file [download feature](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/blob/d470d40c205ce2653bff0ab187794ba8652639e2/docs/file-download.adoc) .
My question is how do I start the fileServer on port 8080 , as I dont see any config option when running Docker ? Do I have to create a new Docker image with FileServer support ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should start automatically. However right now only last 2 versions of all browser images are updated to contain required binaries (e.g. `selenoid/chrome:65.0` and `selenoid/chrome:66.0`). This is going to be fixed during next weeks - when the rest of images are rebuilt.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer . One more question - Its also mentioned that  download directory should be ~/Downloads. Is it created automatically in the container when using chrome:65.0 ?

Comment: Yes, for all new images. https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-images/blob/master/selenium/base/base_3/Dockerfile#L17